# Learning To Make A Class in JS

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am doing a JavaScript course. We are covering objects and creating objects with class. So I created a class making a "Person" with the file book.js

After creating it, I made a separate .js file titled script.js
Used import and export keywords and all.
But when I got to the console to console.log it and it shows me an error saying that it's not defined.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Classes</title>
    <script type="module" src="person.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

From person.js

```
 class Person {
  constructor(
    firstName,
    lastName,
    dateOfbirth,
    Age, 
    Nationality, 
  )
  {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.dateOfbirth = dateOfbirth;
    this.Age = Age;
    this.Nationality = Nationality
  
  }
  
}

export default Person
```

From script.js

```
import Person from "./person.js";

const Shek = new Person (
  John,
  Doe, 
  10111990,
  27,
  'American'
)
```

I am just starting to get into JS so I really want to get this right.

Part of me feels like I might be importing this incorrect cause when I bring in someone else's code I am able to access everything when I console.log.

Comment: When using `import`, you are not adding anything to the global scope so you can't `console.log` it from the console. Is that your question? `You can console.log()` from the script that has access to the variables.

Comment: "But when I got to the console to console.log it and it shows me an error saying that it's not defined" — Where there any other errors? Like a 404 not found for `person` because the URL is `person.js`?

Comment: `<script type="module" src="person.js"></script>` is pointless. `person.js` doesn't *do* anything by itself. It only matters because of what it exports, which is what `import Person from "./person";` is for.

Comment: You need to import `from "./person.js"`, not from `"./person"`. Look at your devtools console for http errors.

Comment: In the course I'm in it's using a class that is defined and they are exporting it into the next document which would be labeled as script.js. My IDE is showing that I successfully imported the class. But when I try to check out the object through console.log(Shek). It says that Shek is undefined.